# Problem with installing NVIDIA drivers on Ubuntu Server

Tags: drivers, 18.04, server, nvidia, graphics

I just tried to install my four NVIDIA GTX 1070 GPUs, but every time I am ready and want to reboot, the screen gets stuck at the same point.

I tried running the following commands:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-390
```

I also tried running `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` -> same scenario.

I also tried to remove the driver from the recovery-mode, but with the following commands nothing really happens:

```
apt-get purge nvidia-390
add-apt-repository --remove ppa:graphics-drivers
```

I am using Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS.

Comment: hello! why don't you just use 19.04? it comes with the latest proprietary nvidia drivers preinstalled. saves you the hassle! :)

Comment: btw ubuntu 19.04 is what I use and I'm a happy gamer.

Comment: hi, i dont now :) the next step after driver installation is to install the CUDA toolkit; I have found a introduction how to install the toolkit and they use 18.04 LTS; Does Cuda work with v19.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to add the graphics drivers PPA to install the version 390 of the Nvidia drivers in Ubuntu 18.04 because that version and newer are already in the official repositories for said release.

However, Nvidia recommends, at the time of this writing, the 430 drivers for a GTX1070.

Please do the following:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-graphics-drivers-430
```

Alternatively, after adding the PPA and refreshing the software sources, the drivers can be installed in GUI at Software&Updates > Additional Drivers by selecting and applying the 430.xx version.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your repliy! Option one does not work because he couldnt find the package "nvidia-graphics-drivers-430" either "nvidia-430"; but your second  idea seems to work :)    BIG THANK YOU! :))))   So now i can uninstall the GUI without problems? Or?